# rvm issue on my VPS

Tags: bash, rvm

As soon as I log into my VPS with ssh I keep getting:

```
-bash: __rvm_add_to_path: command not found
```

When I try:

```
[root@myapp config]# rvm -v
```

I get:

```
-bash: rvm: command not found
```

When I try:

```
[root@myapp config]#  type rvm | head -1
```

I get:

```
-bash: type: rvm: not found
```

So for some days now I've been trying to find out what the problem is. I've just gone into
the root folder of my VPS and opened .bash_history in vi

Some of the latest entries I can see are:

```
cd conf
ls
vi httpd.conf
sudo service httpd restart
rm -rf $HOME/.rvm*
sudo service httpd restart
ls
cd ..
ls
cd home
```

Would I be right in saying that `rm -rf $HOME/ .rvm*` is causing me the problem? (don't remember doing it, but looks like I did, to try fix another issue). How can I undo that, so that my rvm will be working again? Thanks for any help.

Comment: check `grep -rn rvm /etc/profile*`

Comment: Tried that, but Terminal gave me: -bash: check: command not found? Do I need to run it from a particular directory?

Comment: just FYI, "check" was a text directed to you and "`grep -rn rvm /etc/profile*`" was a command to run in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; you uninstalled rvm. Reinstall it by typing `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` in your VPS.